# Como se realiza una búsqueda de una valor que esta dentro de una lista que a su vez esta dentro de un diccionario? Python

Tags: python

muy buenas, estoy creando una función la cual me permita hallar el valor máximo que esta dentro de una lista que a su vez esta dentro de un diccionario pero no se como realmente se realiza algo por el estilo.

ejemplo, tengo este diccionario:

```
mercado = { 1 : ['agua', 50, 80]
2 : ['papas', 210, 10] 
3 : ['jugo de uva', 60, 5]
}
```

ahora, dentro de la lista estaría el 'nombre, precio y unidades'.

entonces lo que intento hacer es buscar por precios el mayor osea (210) pero que se guarde o en un print muestre el nombre osea "papas".

```
def encontrar_mayor_precio() -> str:
```

a la función le añadí:

```
    mayor = max(mercado.keys(precio))
print(mayor)
```

pero creo que esta rotundamente mal inicialmente la cree para verificar que si tenga el valor que es mayor pero quiero imprimir el nombre.

aclaro que quiero hallar el mayor de todas las listas no el mayor de cada una

Comment: Agrega a  tu pregunta   la función que estas haciendo para poder apoyarte.

Comment: quieres hallar el mayor de todas las listas o de cada lista??

Comment: el mayor de todas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la forma más fácil es aplicando la función `max()` y especificar el parámetro `key` el cual indica en base a que obtendrá el máximo.

Para obtener las lista solo hace falta usar el método `values()` de los diccionario, esto regresa una lista de tipo `dicy_values()` pero igual nos es util, ya que sigue siendo un iterable.

```py
producto = max(mercado.values(), key= lambda x: x[1])
print(producto)
```

Aquí le decimos que obtenga el máximo de la lista de valores, pero le decimos que de cada lista solo tome el segundo valor (`x[1]`) y en base a eso nos devuelva el mayor.

**resultado**

```
['papas', 210, 10]
```

Si solo quieres el nombre puedes acceder a ese elemento haciendo `producto[0]`. Existen otras formas de hacerlo pero son mucho más largas.

Comment: Tengo otra duda, como puedo hacer para multiplicar el precio por las unidades?

Comment: al tener el valor de `producto`, dado que es una lista puedes acceder a sus índice, de tal forma `producto[1]*producto[2]` lo puedes aprecias mejor con un `print(f"el producto {producto[0]} vale: {producto[1]*producto[2]}")`

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma es usar la funcion `zip` la cual te devuelve una lista de tuplas segun las listas que le pases:

```
 nombre_percio_unidad = list(zip(*mercado.values()))
```

Acá, la variable `nombre_percio_unidad` tiene la siguiente estructura: `[('agua', 'papas', 'jugo de uva'), (50, 210, 60), (80, 10, 5)]`, es decir, la primera tupla tiene todos los nombres, la segunda tupla todos los precios y la tercera todas las cantidades.

Posteriormente, buscamos en la segunda tupla (la tupla de precios), el elemento mayor y obtenemos su indice, ese indice será el que usaremos en la tupla de nombres. Acá la solucion usando listas por comprensión.

```
producto_max = [nombre_percio_unidad[0][(a,b,c).index(max(a,b,c))] for i, (a, b, c) in enumerate(pares_mercado) if i == 1]
print(prooducto_max[0])
```

O si prefieres no usar listas por comprensión, entonces:

```
for i, (a, b, c) in enumerate(nombre_percio_unidad):
  if (i == 1):
    index = (a,b,c).index(max(a,b,c))
    print(nombre_percio_unidad[0][index])
```

Para ambas versiones, la salida es la misma: `'papas'`

Comment: exactamente esta era mi segunda forma :D

Comment: Creo que es un poco mas larga, pero no está demás dejarla como otra posible respuesta :)